# SQLZOO- using GROUPBY to find the largest country in a continent; is this possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working on a practice problem from SQLZOO, and am not sure why the solution I'm trying doesn't work as it makes sense to me.

This is the format of the table::

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|     name      continent    area    population       gdp     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| Afghanistan     Asia      652230    25500100    20343000000 |
| .                                                           |
| .                                                           |
| .                                                           |
|                                                             |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

The question is the following:

Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area.

Here is the way I was thinking to solve it:

```
SELECT continent, name, area 
  FROM world
 WHERE name IN (SELECT continent, name, MAX(area) 
                  FROM world 
                 GROUP BY continent);
```

I know this doesn't work, but why not? It seems like the nested SELECT statement is finding the country with the MAX area per continent, is it not?

The actual solution for this is something like follows:

```
SELECT continent, name, area 
  FROM world x
 WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area 
       FROM world y
      WHERE y.continent=x.continent
        AND area>0)
```

But this seems like a complicated way of coming up with it;; is this way makes the most sense? Any ideas are appreciated

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While at a quick glimpse this query seems works

```
SELECT continent, name, area 
  FROM world
 WHERE area IN (SELECT MAX(area) 
                  FROM world 
                 GROUP BY continent);
```

[*Demo 1*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12f5d/1)

considering the current data, some issues would raise while some other new records added such as in the demo below. Rather than the above prefer this one :

```
SELECT w1.continent, name, w1.area 
  FROM world AS w1
  JOIN (SELECT continent, MAX(area) AS area
          FROM world 
         GROUP BY continent) AS w2
    ON w1.continent = w2.continent
   AND w1.area = w2.area
```

[*Demo 2*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f26a57/8)

Comment: Thank you so much!! How did you come up with this so quickly?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how did you become so comfortable with SQL? I'm practicing but still not comfortable with it. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately this answer works by accident of the data.  It will return additional, erroneous rows if the area of some some continent's largest country happens to be the same area as, [for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f26a57/2), some other continent's second largest country.

Answer (score 1):

```
select A.continent, W.name, A.area
from
(select continent, max(area) as area from world group by continent)A, world W
where
A.continent = W.continent
and
A.area = W.area
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select continent, name, area
from
(select continent, name, area, rank() over(partition by continent order by area desc) as r1
from world) a
where a.r1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query,

```
SELECT a.continent, name, a.area
FROM
    (
        SELECT continent, max(area) as area
        FROM world 
        GROUP BY continent
        ORDER BY area desc
    ) a 
    join world b on a.area = b.area
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found this query useful.

```
SELECT continent,name,area
FROM  world x
WHERE area >= (SELECT max(area)FROM world y WHERE y.continent = x.continent and area>=0)
```

We are fetching the country details from world table where the area is greater than or equal to the area of all countries where the continent is the same .

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select continent, name, area 
from (select *, rank() over(partition by continent order by area desc)  r from world) s 
where r=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT QWE.CONTINENT, WORLD.NAME, QWE.AREA 
FROM (SELECT CONTINENT, MAX(AREA) AS AREA FROM WORLD GROUP BY CONTINENT) QWE 
JOIN WORLD ON QWE.AREA=WORLD.AREA
```

for an interesting solution

Answer (score 0):

Using the analytical `rank` function, we can do this:

```sql
SELECT continent, name, area 
FROM (
  SELECT *, rank() over(partition BY continent ORDER BY area DESC) AS rn
  FROM world
) a
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY a.area DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

//select name, continent,population from world x where 25000000>= all (select population from world y where y.continent=x.continent)//

I tried this way. It is giving the answer though not a standard procedure may be!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
select continent, name, area 
from world x 
where area = All (select MAX(area) from world where x.continent = continent)
```